# Check utc Date is changed JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

HI All I have requirement like based on local UTC date is changed (day is next or every day at 11 pm) then trigger some action in JS.

```
EX: if(day === nextDay | today===22) {  triggerAction() }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is no such thing as “local UTC date”. GMT is the closest local offset to UTC. So do you want UTC or local (which infers daylight saving where observed)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC using:

```
const start = Date.now();
```

You can get number of full days since Jan 1, 1970 by dividing milliseconds by milliseconds per day:

```
const startDays = Math.floor(start / 86400000);
```

Then you can check if today is a full day past the start:

```
const now = Date.now();
const today = Math.floor(now / 86400000);
if (today > startDays) console.log("Next day!");
```

Then if you need to check it's past a certain time during the day, we convert days back into milliseconds and add milliseconds past midnight as the time of the day:

```
if (now > ((startDays * 86400000) + (23 * 3600000))) 
console.log("Next day 11pm.");
```

In this example, 23 is 11pm in 24h clock and 3600000 is milliseconds per hour.